# Adding/removing menus in Eclipse 4.1 (Customize Perspective not implemented)

Tags: eclipse

According to the [Eclipse wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse/4.1_Known_Issues#End_user_features_to_be_addressed_2), Eclipse 4.x does not have the "customize perspective" option:

> Given the increased flexibility allowed by a modeled UI, we have not put effort in the 4.x release into modeling the same perspective functionality as in Eclipse 3.x.

My question, of course is: how, then, do I add or remove menus from a perspective when I need to?

For example, I need the "Team" menu visible in order to use source control (I still have access via the context menu, but for some reason key shortcuts do not work). Also, I'd like to jettison menus I never use, like "Commands", "Run" and "Navigate"